# Having trouble understanding if x % 4 == 0 and ( x % 100 == 0 and x % 400) == 0

Tags: python, if-statement, parentheses

```
leap_year = int(input('Year: '))
initial_year = leap_year

while True:
    leap_year += 1
    if leap_year % 4 == 0 and (leap_year % 100 == 0 and leap_year % 400) == 0:
        print(f'The next leap year after {initial_year} is {leap_year}')
        break
```

Can someone explain to me how this:

```
if leap_year % 4 == 0 and (leap_year % 100 == 0 and leap_year % 400) == 0:
```

is different from this:

```
if leap_year % 4 == 0 and leap_year % 100 == 0 and leap_year % 400 == 0:
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Can someone explain to me how this:... is different from this:" You first; according to your understanding, **why should they be the same**? Also: [did you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/) to [analyze](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) what each version does? For example, did you try setting some values of `leap_year`, and then seeing what the result is for each part of the expression? Do you understand the order of operations? (In your own words, what is the purpose of parentheses in an expression?)

Comment: In general, it is [not possible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894) to "explain" code, because we don't have a way to know **why** you do not understand it already. Please read [ask].

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Fair enough, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

It's confusing how there's an `== 0` at the end, which is functionally the same as putting `not` before that part. It's also confusing how `leap_year % 400` isn't directly compared against anything, unlike the other modulo operations.*

It'd be clearer to rewrite it:

```
leap_year % 4 == 0 and not (leap_year % 100 == 0 and leap_year % 400 != 0)
```

If we apply [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), it might be even clearer:

```
leap_year % 4 == 0 and (leap_year % 100 != 0 or leap_year % 400 == 0)
```

Lastly, you could remove the parentheses at this point, but it's better for readability to keep them.

Now it should be obvious how it differs from the other condition you mentioned.

---

* *What actually happens there is that the `and` evaluates `leap_year % 100 == 0` and if it's falsy, it yields the result, i.e. `False`; if it's truthy, it yields the result of `leap_year % 400`, i.e. an int in `range(0, 400, 100)`. That gets compared against the `== 0` at the end, and for `False` it works because `False == 0`.*

Comment: There is a comparison against `leap_year % 400` when `leap_year % 100 == 0` is true.

Comment: @Kelly Oh, sorry if I was unclear. I mean `leap_year % 400` isn't being explicitly compared against anything, which breaks the symmetry with the other conditions. Implicitly, it's compared against `!= 0`, so it's easier to read when you add that in and make it explicit. I edited to clarify.

Comment: That implicit comparison doesn't happen. In `a and b`, the truth value of `a` gets checked and if true, the result is `b`. Without checking the truth value of `b`. And in this case, it thus becomes the value of the expression in parentheses, and gets compared with the explicit `== 0`.

Comment: @Kelly Oh yeah, I didn't even think about that... Thankfully the result is still the same though. I'll edit later if I can figure out how to explain that well and the question doesn't get closed.

Comment: It's certainly weird. Rather funny that their weird line is correct and their nice-looking line is wrong.

Comment: @Kelly Yeah, definitely. I edited to add the actual explanation FYI.